# Maven Archetype: Validate artifactId or groupId

Tags: java, maven, maven-archetype

I want to build a Maven archetype that checks whether the supplied artifactId and groupId match a given regex. In this way, I want to enforce the naming conventions of our organisation, e.g. ear files having names ending with `-app` and all groupIds starting with de.companyname.

Is this possible?

I found that you can check against a regex for `requiredProperty`

https://maven.apache.org/archetype/archetype-models/archetype-descriptor/archetype-descriptor.html

but the given value is ignored when I build the archetype through eclipse, which could be due to an old version of the maven-archetype-plugin that is used in eclipse (and this is not applicable to "build-in" properties like groupId or artifactId).

Comment: http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/documentation/release-notes-17.html shows that m2e still uses maven-archetype-plugin 2.4, so no regex validation for requiredProperties. That part is solved.

Answer (score 6):

This:

```
  <requiredProperties>
    <requiredProperty key=.. >
      <defaultValue/>
      <validationRegex/>
    </requiredProperty>
  </requiredProperties>
```

... **is** the way to define a required property (with defaults and validation). However, IIRC, it was introduced in v3.0.0 of the archetype plugin so perhaps you are using a prior version.

**Edit 1**: in response to this question "can validationRegex be applied to artifactId and groupId". Yes, it can. It can be applied to any entry in `requiredProperties` but with this caveat: `validationRegex` only works for inputs supplied at the command line, so providing a `defaultValue` or defining a value via a command line parameter (`-DgroupId=...`, `-DartifactId=...` ) side steps validation. Here's a concrete example, given the following `requiredProperties` in `archetype-descriptor.xml`:

```
<requiredProperties>
  <requiredProperty key="artifactId">
    <validationRegex>^[a-z]*$</validationRegex>
  </requiredProperty>
  <requiredProperty key="groupId">
    <defaultValue>COM.XYZ.PQR</defaultValue>
    <validationRegex>^[a-z]*$</validationRegex>
  </requiredProperty>
</requiredProperties>
```

The following command: `mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=... -DarchetypeArtifactId=... -DarchetypeVersion=... -DgroupId=com.foo.bar` will result in `com.foo.bar` being used for groupId and the user will be prompted to supply an artifactId like so:

> Define value for property 'username' (should match expression '^[a-z]*$'): Whatever
>
> Value does not match the expression, please try again: whatever
>
> Define value for property...

So far so good (sort of).

But the following command `mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=... -DarchetypeArtifactId=... -DarchetypeVersion=... -DartifactId=whatever` will result in `COM.XYZ.PQR` being used for groupId even though that does not conform to the `validationRegex`.

Similarly; the following command `mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=... -DarchetypeArtifactId=... -DarchetypeVersion=... -DartifactId=WHATEVER` will result in `COM.XYZ.PQR` being used for groupId and `WHATEVER` being used for artifactId even though those values do not conform to the `validationRegex`.

So, in summary: the `validationRegex` works for any requiredProperty (whether its a *reserved property* - such as artifactId - or a bespoke property) but it only applies to values which are provided interactively and hence setting a default value or supplying a value via a command line parameter side steps validation.

Note: even if you do use `validationRegex` you might also want to consider using the Maven Enforcer Plugin's [requireProperty rule](https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/requireProperty.html) because thes project properties you wan to enforce could be changed after the archetype has been used to create the project. From the docs:

> This rule can enforce that a declared property is set and optionally evaluate it against a regular expression.

Here's an example:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>enforce-property</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>enforce</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <rules>
            <requireProperty>
              <property>project.artifactId</property>
              <message>"Project artifactId must match ...some naming convention..."</message>
              <regex>...naming convention regex...</regex>
              <regexMessage>"Project artifactId must ..."</regexMessage>
            </requireProperty>
          </rules>
          <fail>true</fail>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Comment: Thank you, but can validationRegex be applied to artifactId and groupId?

Comment: Yes, as long as those parameter values are provided interactively. I've updated the answer to make this clear.

Comment: for groupId this works using dots:  <validationRegex><![CDATA[^[a-z\\.]*$]]></validationRegex>  .